# How to obtain images with transparency in an easy way?

Tags: wpf, image, f#

Playing with F# and wpf and so far, I like it. Not being a graphics designer, though I am looking for a sneaky way to achieve the following:

I have the outline of a picture (from a png -> svg -> xps -> xaml path). If I were into manual graphics program using, I would now probably spend half a day or more to get the following variations: Outline partially filled with [black, white], partially filled with transparency, then save those images and use them in my code. But...I feel it should be possible to use the xaml path of the outline along with a few lines of code to achieve the same without much clicking...

To clarify the idea, here a sample picture just to show what I have in mind:

Input:

[image: Outline of one of the pictures]

Now, the background and some parts of the picture need to be transparent, some others be filled with either white or black, the outline, either white or black, too. As mentioned, I found a way to get a xaml path object from the picture and now I look for a cool way to "transmogrify" the picture into those 4,5 variations. It will pay off as there are a few more similar pictures which need the same treatment.

When I have them all, each will be a `Image` instance in my code, which will be positioned inside a `Canvas`.

Cool ideas how to get it done, anyone?

The basic code framework I currently have works like this:

```
let visual renderer w h =
    let dvis = System.Windows.Media.DrawingVisual()
    let d = dvis.RenderOpen()
    renderer d w h
    d.Close()
    let bmp = Windows.Media.Imaging.RenderTargetBitmap(int w, int h, 96.0,96.0,Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Pbgra32)
    let img = System.Windows.Controls.Image()
    bmp.Render(dvis)
    img.Source <- bmp
    img

let redCircle w h =
    visual 
        (fun d w h -> 
            let r = (min w h)/2. * 0.9
            d.DrawEllipse(System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red,null,System.Windows.Point(w/2.0,h/2.0),r,r)
        ) w h
```

... and just like in the `redCircle` function, I would render the path to the image inside a lambda...

Comment: Maybe you are wondering, why no one told you the answer yet. IMO there is no easy and cool way to do what you desire.

Comment: @netaholic Right now I think about somehow splitting the path into sections and then use some geometry stuff somehow...